# Is The Misalignment caused by the misuse of Relative and Absolute

Tags: html, css

1. Why won't it align properly ?
2. When class sectMid has the correct width which has been commented out the layout isn't proper at all although the sizes of the respective divs equate to it.
3. Is the complications with the layout due to the misuse of relative and absolute in the div positioning ?

I am not sure if i may have a small issue or maybe the technique which i am trying to use is flawed. my hope is so all the pieces fit and there are no spaces in between the sections to make the piece a whole unit. The background of the middle section is just there for a guide. this concept was designed to emulate a prototype navbar. the content of each circle has not been aligned properly. The positioning of the text isn't an issue for now.

```css
body{
 background: #202020;
}

.tabCnt{
 position: relative;
 border-radius: 50%;
}

.type1{
 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 background: white;
}

.type2{

 width: 100px;
 height: 100px;
 left:20px;
 top:20px;
 background: green;
}

.tabCnt2{
 position: relative;
 border-radius: 50%;
 width: 140px;
 height: 140px;
 background: brown;

}

.sectMid{
 width: 470px;/*440px*/
 height: 140px;
background: blue;}

.type1A{
 display: inline-block;
}

.vert{
 left:170px;
}

.yLine{
 width: 0;
 height: 50px;
 border-left: 8px solid black;
 position:relative;
 border-color: pink;
 left: 216px;
}

.xLine{
 top: 46px;
 width: 50px;
 height: 0px;
 border-bottom: 8px solid black;
 position:relative;
 border-color: pink;
 
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title>Personal Website</title>
</head>

<body>
 <div class= "navbarBig navbarSmall">
  <div class = "tabCnt type1 vert" style="text-align: center;"><br><br>PROJECTS</div>
  <div class = "yLine"></div>
  <div class= "sectMid">
   <div class = "tabCnt type1 type1A" style="float: left;top: 20px;text-align: center;"><br><br>RESUME</div>
   <div class = "xLine type1A"></div>
   <div class = "tabCnt2 type1A">
    <div class = "tabCnt type2">Active Tab Icon</div>
   </div>
   <div class = "xLine type1A"></div>
   <div class = "tabCnt type1 type1A" style="float: right;top: 20px;text-align: center;"><br><br>ABOUT<br>ME</div>
  </div>
  <div class = "yLine"></div>
  <div class = "tabCnt type1 vert" style="text-align: center;"><br><br>VIDEOS</div>
  
 </div>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: am not able to understand what is your issue ? ... you are using relative positionning with all fixed value and you got this which is logic, so ? what is your issue ? you expect what ?

Comment: there seems to be a gap between the lines and the circles. i cant seem to figure out why. i thought it was due to my choice of positioning . i just recently started programming with html and i am not too sure what the issue could be. there seems to be an extra margin thats making the measurements incorrrect